# Running impala-shell from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, hive, cloudera, impala

I am trying to run impala from jupyter-notebook as follows--

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='xx-xx-xx.xx.com', 
               port=21000,
               auth_mechanism="PLAIN",
               user='xxxx',
               password='xxxx',
              )
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

But I am getting this error

```
TTransportException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-6c858acffc1b> in <module>
.
.
TTransportException: Bad status: 3 (b'Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN')
```

After trying out many things which did not work I thought to run impala command as python `subprocess.run` but I am getting no output (return code 1)--

```py
r = subprocess.run(['impala-shell', '-q', "select xxx...xxx"],
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(r.stdout.decode()) # returncode=1
```

Also `!impala-shell` in jupyter giving this error

```
File "/opt/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/impala-shell/impala_shell.py", line 262
    print "Query options (defaults shown in []):"
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone let me know the problem and guide me on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem yet? It might be because of a startup error caused by a python version.

Comment: yes might be the cause, but it was long back I moved on to different project and company 

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Python version.

Impala is compatible with python version 2.7.5, and most probably you would be using python version 3 or higher.

To fix this,

- either you can downgrade your python,
- or can create a virtual environment using Python 2, and run impala from that virtual environment.

To create virtual environment, follow below steps:

```
virtualenv venv -p python2
cd venv
source bin/activate
(venv) impala-shell
```